# SAPUI5: Router instance not accessible when router configuration is specified in manifest.json

Tags: sapui5

I'm not able to access the router instance  in one of the controller event handlers. This code generates an error:

```
var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
oRouter.navTo("next");
```

The router is initialized in *Component.js* using the code:

```
this.getRouter().initialize();
```

It's loading perfectly in *Component.js* but in the controller method it's returning as `undefined`.

Do I need to initialize the router in any controller methods to access it in event handlers of the controller?

I am maintaining the router configuration in a *manifest.json* file.

Comment: Make sure that **this** references the controller instance not a source of the event.

Comment: Need either a jsbin or screenshot of folder structure. Can you create a small example and provide the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my **this** is referring to source of event its failing, thanks
[slkorolev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/977177/slkorolev) for the suggestion.its working now.

i have changed my code to refer to controller instance instead to event source